# Eclipse WindowBuilder error with NullPoInterException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

The version of my eclipse is indigo.

I've installed WindowBuilder through

```
Help --> Insttall New Software
```

However, when I launch the new project with WindowBuilder

I got the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.SourcePage.updateSourceActions(SourcePage.java:140)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.SourcePage.handleActiveState(SourcePage.java:74)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.MultiPagesMode.showSource(MultiPagesMode.java:54)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.MultiPagesMode.create(MultiPagesMode.java:100)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DesignerEditor.createPartControl(DesignerEditor.java:87)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:315)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2946)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2846)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2777)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$2.handleEvent(OpenWithMenu.java:180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

The following is other plugins I installed for running WindowBuilder:

1. Swing Designer
2. SWT Designer
3. SWT Designer Core
4. SWT Designer SWT_AWT Support
5. SWT Designer XWT Support
6. Usage Data Collector    1.4.0.R201106061540
7. WindowBuilder Core  1.3.0.r37x201202052311
8. WindowBuilder Core Documentation    1.3.0.r37x201202052336
9. WindowBuilder Core UI   1.3.0.r37x201202052340
10. WindowBuilder GroupLayout Support  1.3.0.r37x201202060028
11. WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST)  1.3.0.r37x201202052344

Please let me know if you know how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to start eclipse with -clean ...also check this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374590

Comment: Thanks. This issue was solved by installing Luna version. : )

Comment: After some time, I've realized that this bug is just random. It appears when there's no reason for a NullPointerException. Restarting Eclipse often solves it, or even opening the same file with GWT Designer instead of WindowBuilder.